# web service using json and XMLHttpRequest javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am developing a chrome extension, and I want to be able to control it's function using key authentication. Each key will dispatch json to be sent to the browser using JavaScript. I am stuck because of the same origin policy. What is my best option to be able to parse this json data from the chrome extension and still retain security?

json data

```
{"valid":"true","info":{"id":"15","username":"johndoe","expire":"1340470800"}}
```

browser request using javascript

```
var xmlhttp;
function loadXMLDoc(url, cfunc) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = cfunc;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

loadXMLDoc("http://website.com/user_data.php?key=3455-2534-7765-2335&username=johndoe", function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      var json = xmlhttp.responseText;
      alert(json);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Chrome and Firefox support [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/cors/raw-file/tip/Overview.html).

Read about the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` HTTP header on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) and [W3C](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/cors/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#access-control-allow-origin-response-header).

Since you are developing a browser extension, you might want to set: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Sending headers with PHP is done with the header function.

Comment: i was reading about that header option isn't that a security vulnerability?

Comment: If you know from which domain you are calling, don't use the `*` value, and instead set the expected caller domain name. This way you will only authorize requests from a specific domain. This security restriction exists in javascript as a sandbox, to prevent attackers from making zombie DDoS requests using hidden scripts on websites. If you use the `*` option you increase the chances of success of an DDoS directed at your server. Otherwise, using Access-Control-Allow-Origin with specific domain names isn't a security vulnerability (if you consider DDoS a security vulnerability).

Comment: "if you consider DDoS a security vulnerability" What I mean is that you could have checked on PHP side the Host HTTP header and implemented a security restriction. What we discussed above is only a security vulnerability from the client browser point of view (a browser is protected with that origin check, from becoming a DDoS zombie).

Comment: If you are exposing functions which modify something (such as update/alter/insert) or would return private information based on credentials, you should add some sort of authorization to your RPC.